# XSD for a cXML file

Tags: xsd, sap-ariba, cxml-commercexml

I wonder if someone could help me to find an XSD of an cXML file (used for Ariba punch out e-commerce transactions).

Best regards,
Stef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cXML have DTDs and they doesn't have the XSD defined. cXML DTD can be downloaded from http://www.sagehill.net/livedtd/cxml/cXML.dtd.html

Taken from their user guide

Basic cXML documents - http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML//cXML.dtd

Confirmation and Ship Notice - http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML//Fulfill.dtd

Invoice - http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML//InvoiceDetail.dtd

Type Definition - http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML//Catalog.dtd

Payment Remittance - http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML//PaymentRemittance.dtd

Answer (score 1):

You can covert the cXML DTD into a schema yourself using tools like [XMLPad](http://www.wmhelp.com/). I found it to be most accurate.

Comment: God bless you mate.
How to convert  :
Goto xmlpad tool.
Drop your cxml.dtd file.
Click DTD ->Convert to XSD
Use the 3rd .xsd generated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly any dtd2xsd converter which I know can not do this conversion (cxml.dtd to cxml.xsd) correctly. If anyone can do it - write how. I need xsf file to generate java classes (xjc can not do it from published dtd file).